# How can I calculate percentage column

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage

Sorry, I've had to adjust my question.

Using SQL Server 2016, I have the summated results from a query into a new table, which looks like this:

| Product | Total Sales | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | 596.42 | 0.00 |
| Product A | 127.55 | 0.00 |
| Product A | 736.83 | 0.00 |
| Product B | 379.51 | 0.00 |
| Product B | 205.95 | 0.00 |
| Product C | 905.99 | 0.00 |

I added the `Percentage` column so I could update that column with the percentage based on the overall total sales for each Product.

For example, I'm trying to achieve the below percentage results from the above table.

| Product | Total Sales | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | 596.42 | 40.83 |
| Product A | 127.55 | 8.73 |
| Product A | 736.83 | 50.44 |
| Product B | 379.51 | 64.82 |
| Product B | 205.95 | 35.18 |
| Product C | 905.99 | 100.00 |

How do I achieve this with an `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: You don't need new table. All you need os to create proper query.

Comment: You don't add columns for data that you can query on demand. It would be better to add a subquery to the select that adds this column to result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the `Percentage` column like so:

```
update tbl
set Percentage = ([Total Sales]/(select sum([Total Sales]) from tbl)) * 100
```

[Fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b8474eae15395e513e183049cf911ca7)

Answer (score 1):

This may depend on your DBMS, if supported you can use `OVER()` to sum up all the rows

```
SELECT 
  TOTAL_SALES / SUM(TOTAL_SALES) OVER() AS PERCENT_OF_SALES
FROM TABLE
```

If unsupported you can use a subquery

```
SELECT 
  TOTAL_SALES / (SELECT SUM(TOTAL_SALES) FROM TABLE) AS PERCENT_OF_SALES
FROM TABLE
```

For an update statement depending on your DBMS you can do something like

```
DECLARE @d INT = (SELECT SUM(TOTAL_SALES) FROM TABLE)

UPDATE TABLE
SET PERCENT_OF_SALES = SALES / @d
```

Answer (score 0):

With Mysql :

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM test INTO @tot;
UPDATE test SET percent = 100 * total / @tot ;
```

DBFiddle example : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hERoW3LajH9tMhjQJUKHER/1